# My PC is using my CPU instead of my GPU and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: firefox, gpu, gpu-driver, webgl

I got a error in firefox saying WebGL was unavailable so I went into firefox's settings and saw that it was not recognizing my gpu and sure enough it looks like its not using it at all... under settings.about it says that the graphics are handled by "Mesa Intel Graphics" when It should be using my 3080. Curious if anyone can help me fix this. Thank you!

Images of settings, drivers, and firefox graphics config:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try selecting an Nvidia proprietary driver, like the 525 or 530 in your "Additional Drivers" tab, instead of the nouveau driver.